# Вопрос о curl php

Tags: php, curl

Поставил куки, заголовки, и делаю запрос на сайт site.com
Получил ответ, и тут проблема, мне нужно еще раз отправить запрос не закрывая соединение. 
Вопрос.
Нужно ли мне обратно отправлять заголовки, куки, то есть продублировать код? 
И еще, есть ли разница в каком порядки отправлять заголовки?
Так
host: rrt 
Tred: gole
Или так
Tred: gole
host: rrt

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете ввиду нужно ли снова устанавливать заголовки через `curl_setopt`? Нет, не надо (отправятся те же заголовки, что и в первом запросе). Узнать об этом вы можете, установив опцию `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` и проанализировав вывод. Порядок заголовков не важен.